# How to reduce the mysql query loading time

Tags: php, mysql

We have website regarding directory listing and we have different association wise data in the database in different tables. We have search functionality on website which search data globally from all associations and another one which search from single association.

- By default it loads all the data with union of all tables, if not write any keyword for search.
- If we write any keyword for search then it will search data from all the associations with check keyword in 25 fields of the tables and then order the first 30 data by some field and returns the rows.

One of the table from the association (companies_general) which has 10+ million data and because of this, sql query takes a long time to execute.if we just try to get all data with union and ordering still it takes a long time almost 1 minute to get the results.

When we exclude that table from query then it takes less time compared to it.

- For solving this issue I used full text search feature with full text index in required fields.but still not able to reduce the amount of time.

So I need solution for this.

Comment: Have you already think about ElasticSearch? ElasticSearch is more powerful than mysql for searching.

Comment: This is a job better suited to [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Full text indexing and search is a very complex topic in itself, as soon as you need to search masses of information you should be indexing using a dedicated indexer like Sphinx Search.

Comment: Can you use stored procedures on your server?  A stored procedure will always perform better than a local query.

Comment: @SPlatten this is not always true, and what the OP is asking of the database is far too much even for a stored procedure. The OP needs to either design and develop an indexer into the product, or use a already tested and tuned indexer like Sphinx.

Comment: @Geoffrey, depends entirely on what you do and how you do it, like anything, but the very fact that you are running on the server is much more faster.  If you take exactly the same task and try to compare running it client side or on the server in a separate process it will be much slower than doing exactly the same in a stored procedure.